# Calculate maximum of every list for a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell, max

How can I define a function in Haskell, which gets a list of lists of doubles, and return the highest value of each list using `map`?

Like this: `func4 [[2,4],[4,7],[7,9]] = [4,7,9]`.

I tried to do it in many ways, but it goes wrong. Is it possible to perform this operation?

```
func4 [[x,y]] = map maximum [x,y]
```

and

```
func4 [[x,y]] = [xs| xs <- map maximum [x,y]]
```

Comment: It's like func4 [[2,4],[4,7],[7,9]] -> [4,7,9]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because `func4` expects - as you say yourself - a list of lists. So `[[x,y]]` is a list of lists. Now that means that `[x,y]` is a list of *items*. You cannot know for sure that `x` and `y` are lists themselves where you can calculate the `maximum` from (and even if that works, it is not correct).

you can simply omit the `[[x,y]]` pattern and use `l` (the list of lists), like:

```
func4 :: Ord b => [[b]] -> [b]
func4 l = map maximum l
```

Or even better, use *eta-reduction*:

```
-- with eta-reduction

func4 :: Ord b => [[b]] -> [b]
func4 = map maximum -- look mom... no variables
```

If it is a **requirement that every list contains exactly two elements**, you can also use:

```
func4 :: Ord b => [[b]] -> [b]
func4 = map (\[x,y] -> max x y)
```

Here you do pattern matching on the item, and it must be a list with two elements `x` and `y` you then `map` on the `max x y`. This function will error if it has to map a list not containing **exactly two elements**. The `\[x,y] -> max x y` is called a *lambda expression*.

Comment: Do you really need a `Foldable t` type definition or just `[[b]]` would suffice like `Ord b => [[b]] -> [b]`?

Comment: @Redu: Well the most generic type signature is `Foldable t`, but I guess it is indeed better to use `[[b]]` here, since `Foldable` is a bit harder to understand than a list I guess.

Comment: Well... i was just being curious about what other types than a list would benefit. It's my limitation :)

Comment: @Redu: well the advantage of `Foldable` is that one can use for instance a binary tree, make it foldable, and then we can calculate the maximum of binary trees as well. Usually it is a good idea to use type classes (although that is only my own experience).